# Quick Replies on the Page Owner

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Messenger Platform introduced [Quick Replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies) feature, that the User can tap to answer Page Owner's request instead of typing. However, I can make it work from the User view only. ***Will it work from Page Owner's view, like suggestion?***

**Flow may be:**

```
1. User ask Page a question
2. Bot suggest some <quick replies> based on that question (maybe use NLP)
3. Page Owner can tap <quick replies> to reply
```

I may call this "semi-auto reply bot". For example, in the demo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpG8M.png), the shop owner may double checked the response and tap to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a direct way to do this. Theoretically you could basically have a customer-facing bot and a business-owner-facing bot, and then orchestrate the a flow something like this:

1. user messages user-facing bot
2. bot forwards the message to business in business-owner-facing bot with quick replies
3. business owner selects a quick reply
4. user-facing bot replies with the text of the quick reply.

You'd want to be careful of privacy concerns tho since the user's message is being forwarded on.